# Change stroke color of a linestring (different from fill color) in node-red

Tags: polygon, geojson, node-red, multilinestring

I'm working on a worldmap in node-red and I was able to create a polygon and a linestring. But I need the linestring to have no fill and cannot differentiate between the line color (stroke color) and the fill color (it always has fill, like it was a polygon).

I've tried this, but no luck:

```
"properties": {
    "stroke": "#555555",
    "stroke-width": 2,
    "stroke-opacity": 1,
    "fill": "#00f900",
    "fill-opacity": 0.5
},
```

This is where I declare the linestring:

```
 var geo = { "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                    [-1.356221,51.048611],
                    [-1.356039,51.048672],
                    [-1.355765,51.048311],
            ]
        },
        "properties": {
            "color": "rgb(168, 5, 57)",
        },
    }]
}
```

The linestring is being presented on the map, but, besides the atual line, it also as a background on the same color as the line, like if it was a polygon.

[image: Check the printscreen of the result here]

Answer (score 0):

```
fill-color : none
```

it should be find